# Controller is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, spotify

Thanks for your help in advance. I'm new to Angular and somewhat new to Javascript and I've run into an issue that I can't seem to resolve.

For some reason, WebStorm is telling me that my imported controller isn't defined. I'm referencing it from another file, which has been imported. I'm trying to use the Spotify API with the angular-js web wrapper.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='app'>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="spec/lib/angular-spotify/src/angular-spotify.js"></script>
    <script src="spec/lib/angular-spotify/examples/main.controller.js"></script>
    <title>angular-spotify demo!</title>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style: none;
        }

        .media {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
        }

            .media img {
                display: table-cell;
                max-width: 100%;
            }

        .media-details {
            padding-left: 1em;
            vertical-align: middle;
            display: table-cell;
            width: 90%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller='test'>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app');
        app.controller('test');
    </script>
    <!--<button ng-click="login()">Login with Spotify</button>
    <button ng-click="login()">Login with Spotify</button>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchartist" ng-change="searchArtist()" placeholder="Search for an artist">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="artist in artists">
            <a class="media" ng-href="{{artist.external_urls.spotify}}" target="_blank">
             <img ng-src="{{artist.images[0].url}}" alt="">
                 <div class="media-details">
                {{artist.name}}
                 </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>-->
    <script>
        asdf = test.getAlbum();
        console.log(asdf);
    </script>
    <h1>hello</h1>
    <h1></h1>
    <h1>hellooo</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.controller.js**

```
angular
  .module('app', ['spotify'])
  .config(function (SpotifyProvider) {
    SpotifyProvider.setClientId('3ab9db5d12614f7c9af32000adeafe1d');
    SpotifyProvider.setRedirectUri('callback.html');
    SpotifyProvider.setScope('user-read-private playlist-read-private playlist-modify-private playlist-modify-public');
  })
  .controller('test', ['$scope', 'Spotify', function($scope, Spotify) {

    $scope.searchArtist = function () {
      Spotify.search($scope.searchArtist, 'artist').then(function (data) {
        $scope.artists = data.artists.items;
      });
    };

    $scope.login = function () {
      Spotify.login().then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert("You are now logged in");
      }, function () {
        console.log('didn\'t log in');
      })
    };

    // Gets an album
    Spotify.getAlbum('0sNOF9WDwhWunNAHPD3Baj').then(function (data){
      console.log('=================== Album - ID ===================');
      return data.name;
    });
    // Works with Spotify uri too
    Spotify.getAlbum('spotify:album:0sNOF9WDwhWunNAHPD3Baj').then(function (data){
      console.log('=================== Album - Spotify URI ===================');
      console.log(data);
    });

    //Get multiple Albums
    Spotify.getAlbums('41MnTivkwTO3UUJ8DrqEJJ,6JWc4iAiJ9FjyK0B59ABb4,6UXCm6bOO4gFlDQZV5yL37').then(function (data) {
      console.log('=================== Albums - Ids ===================');
      console.log(data);
    });
    Spotify.getAlbums(['41MnTivkwTO3UUJ8DrqEJJ','6JWc4iAiJ9FjyK0B59ABb4','6UXCm6bOO4gFlDQZV5yL37']).then(function (data) {
      console.log('=================== Albums - Array ===================');
      console.log(data);
    });


    Spotify.getAlbumTracks('41MnTivkwTO3UUJ8DrqEJJ').then(function (data) {
      console.log('=================== Album Tracks - ID ===================');
      console.log(data);
    });
    Spotify.getAlbumTracks('spotify:album:41MnTivkwTO3UUJ8DrqEJJ').then(function (data) {
      console.log('=================== Album Tracks - Spotify URI ===================');
      console.log(data);
    });



    //Artist
    Spotify.getArtist('0LcJLqbBmaGUft1e9Mm8HV').then(function (data) {
      console.log('=================== Artist - Id ===================');
      console.log(data);
    });
    Spotify.getArtist('spotify:artist:0LcJLqbBmaGUft1e9Mm8HV').then(function (data) {
      console.log('=================== Artist - Spotify URI ===================');
      console.log(data);
    });

    Spotify.getArtistAlbums('0LcJLqbBmaGUft1e9Mm8HV').then(function (data) {
      console.log('=================== Artist Albums - Id ===================');
      console.log(data);
    });

    Spotify.getArtistAlbums('spotify:artist:0LcJLqbBmaGUft1e9Mm8HV').then(function (data) {
      console.log('=================== Artist Albums - Spotify URI ===================');
      console.log(data);
    });

    Spotify.getArtistTopTracks('0LcJLqbBmaGUft1e9Mm8HV', 'AU').then(function (data) {
      console.log('=================== Artist Top Tracks Australia ===================');
      console.log(data);
    });

    Spotify.getRelatedArtists('0LcJLqbBmaGUft1e9Mm8HV').then(function (data) {
      console.log('=================== Get Releated Artists ===================');
      console.log(data);
    });


    //Tracks
    Spotify.getTrack('0eGsygTp906u18L0Oimnem').then(function (data) {
      console.log('=================== Track ===================');
      console.log(data);
    });

    Spotify.getTracks('0eGsygTp906u18L0Oimnem,1lDWb6b6ieDQ2xT7ewTC3G').then(function (data) {
      console.log('=================== Tracks - String ===================');
      console.log(data);
    });

    Spotify.getTracks(['0eGsygTp906u18L0Oimnem','1lDWb6b6ieDQ2xT7ewTC3G']).then(function (data) {
      console.log('=================== Tracks - Array ===================');
      console.log(data);
    });

  }]);
```

**angular-spotify.js**

```
(function (window, angular, undefined) {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('spotify', [])
    .provider('Spotify', function () {

      // Module global settings.
      var settings = {};
      settings.clientId = null;
      settings.redirectUri = null;
      settings.scope = null;
      settings.authToken = null;

      this.setClientId = function (clientId) {
        settings.clientId = clientId;
        return settings.clientId;
      };

      this.getClientId = function () {
        return settings.clientId;
      };

      this.setAuthToken = function (authToken) {
        settings.authToken = authToken;
        return settings.authToken;
      };

      this.setRedirectUri = function (redirectUri) {
        settings.redirectUri = redirectUri;
        return settings.redirectUri;
      };

      this.getRedirectUri = function () {
        return settings.redirectUri;
      };

      this.setScope = function (scope) {
        settings.scope = scope;
        return settings.scope;
      };

      var utils = {};
      utils.toQueryString = function (obj) {
        var parts = [];
        angular.forEach(obj, function (value, key) {
          this.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value));
        }, parts);
        return parts.join('&');
      };

      /**
       * API Base URL
       */
      settings.apiBase = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1';

      this.$get = ['$q', '$http', '$window', function ($q, $http, $window) {

        function NgSpotify () {
          this.clientId = settings.clientId;
          this.redirectUri = settings.redirectUri;
          this.apiBase = settings.apiBase;
          this.scope = settings.scope;
          this.authToken = settings.authToken;
          this.toQueryString = utils.toQueryString;
        }

        function openDialog (uri, name, options, cb) {
          var win = window.open(uri, name, options);
          var interval = window.setInterval(function () {
            try {
              if (!win || win.closed) {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                cb(win);
              }
            } catch (e) {}
          }, 1000);
          return win;
        }

        NgSpotify.prototype = {
          api: function (endpoint, method, params, data, headers) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({
              url: this.apiBase + endpoint,
              method: method ? method : 'GET',
              params: params,
              data: data,
              headers: headers
            })
            .success(function (data) {
              deferred.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function (data) {
              deferred.reject(data);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
          },

          _auth: function (isJson) {
            var auth = {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authToken
            };
            if (isJson) {
              auth['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
            }
            return auth;
          },

          /**
           * Search Spotify
           * q = search query
           * type = artist, album or track
           */
          search: function (q, type, options) {
            options = options || {};
            options.q = q;
            options.type = type;

            return this.api('/search', 'GET', options);
          },

          /**
            ====================== Albums =====================
           */

          /**
           * Gets an album
           * Pass in album id or spotify uri
           */
          getAlbum: function (album) {
            album = album.indexOf('spotify:') === -1 ? album : album.split(':')[2];

            return this.api('/albums/' + album);
          },

          /**
           * Gets an album
           * Pass in comma separated string or array of album ids
           */
          getAlbums: function (albums) {
            albums = angular.isString(albums) ? albums.split(',') : albums;
            angular.forEach(albums, function (value, index) {
              albums[index] = value.indexOf('spotify:') > -1 ? value.split(':')[2] : value;
            });
            return this.api('/albums', 'GET', {
              ids: albums ? albums.toString() : ''
            });
          },

          /**
           * Get Album Tracks
           * Pass in album id or spotify uri
           */
          getAlbumTracks: function (album, options) {
            album = album.indexOf('spotify:') === -1 ? album : album.split(':')[2];

            return this.api('/albums/' + album + '/tracks', 'GET', options);
          },

          /**
            ====================== Artists =====================
           */

          /**
           * Get an Artist
           */
          getArtist: function (artist) {
            artist = artist.indexOf('spotify:') === -1 ? artist : artist.split(':')[2];

            return this.api('/artists/' + artist);
          },

          /**
           * Get multiple artists
           */
          getArtists: function (artists) {
            artists = angular.isString(artists) ? artists.split(',') : artists;
            angular.forEach(artists, function (value, index) {
              artists[index] = value.indexOf('spotify:') > -1 ? value.split(':')[2] : value;
            });
            return this.api('/artists/', 'GET', {
              ids: artists ? artists.toString() : ''
            });
          },

          //Artist Albums
          getArtistAlbums: function (artist, options) {
            artist = artist.indexOf('spotify:') === -1 ? artist : artist.split(':')[2];

            return this.api('/artists/' + artist + '/albums', 'GET', options);
          },

          /**
           * Get Artist Top Tracks
           * The country: an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code.
           */
          getArtistTopTracks: function (artist, country) {
            artist = artist.indexOf('spotify:') === -1 ? artist : artist.split(':')[2];

            return this.api('/artists/' + artist + '/top-tracks', 'GET', {
              country: country
            });
          },

          getRelatedArtists: function (artist) {
            artist = artist.indexOf('spotify:') === -1 ? artist : artist.split(':')[2];

            return this.api('/artists/' + artist + '/related-artists');
          },


          /**
            ====================== Tracks =====================
           */
          getTrack: function (track) {
            track = track.indexOf('spotify:') === -1 ? track : track.split(':')[2];

            return this.api('/tracks/' + track);
          },

          getTracks: function (tracks) {
            tracks = angular.isString(tracks) ? tracks.split(',') : tracks;
            angular.forEach(tracks, function (value, index) {
              tracks[index] = value.indexOf('spotify:') > -1 ? value.split(':')[2] : value;
            });
            return this.api('/tracks/', 'GET', {
              ids: tracks ? tracks.toString() : ''
            });
          },


          /**
            ====================== Playlists =====================
           */
          getUserPlaylists: function (userId, options) {
            return this.api('/users/' + userId + '/playlists', 'GET', options, null, {
              'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authToken
            });
          },

          getPlaylist: function (userId, playlistId, options) {
            return this.api('/users/' + userId + '/playlists/' + playlistId, 'GET', options, null, this._auth());
          },

          getPlaylistTracks: function (userId, playlistId, options) {
            return this.api('/users/' + userId + '/playlists/' + playlistId + '/tracks', 'GET', options, null, this._auth());
          },

          createPlaylist: function (userId, options) {
            return this.api('/users/' + userId + '/playlists', 'POST', null, options, this._auth(true));
          },

          addPlaylistTracks: function (userId, playlistId, tracks, options) {
            tracks = angular.isArray(tracks) ? tracks : tracks.split(',');
            angular.forEach(tracks, function (value, index) {
              tracks[index] = value.indexOf('spotify:') === -1 ? 'spotify:track:' + value : value;
            });
            return this.api('/users/' + userId + '/playlists/' + playlistId + '/tracks', 'POST', {
              uris: tracks.toString(),
              position: options ? options.position : null
            }, null, this._auth(true));
          },

          removePlaylistTracks: function (userId, playlistId, tracks) {
            tracks = angular.isArray(tracks) ? tracks : tracks.split(',');
            var track;
            angular.forEach(tracks, function (value, index) {
              track = tracks[index];
              tracks[index] = {
                uri: track.indexOf('spotify:') === -1 ? 'spotify:track:' + track : track
              };
            });
            return this.api('/users/' + userId + '/playlists/' + playlistId + '/tracks', 'DELETE', null, {
              tracks: tracks
            }, this._auth(true));
          },

          reorderPlaylistTracks: function (userId, playlistId, options) {
            return this.api('/users/' + userId + '/playlists/' + playlistId + '/tracks', 'PUT', null, options, this._auth(true));
          },

          replacePlaylistTracks: function (userId, playlistId, tracks) {
            tracks = angular.isArray(tracks) ? tracks : tracks.split(',');
            var track;
            angular.forEach(tracks, function (value, index) {
              track = tracks[index];
              tracks[index] = track.indexOf('spotify:') === -1 ? 'spotify:track:' + track : track;
            });
            return this.api('/users/' + userId + '/playlists/' + playlistId + '/tracks', 'PUT', {
              uris: tracks.toString()
            }, null, this._auth(true));
          },

          updatePlaylistDetails: function (userId, playlistId, options) {
            return this.api('/users/' + userId + '/playlists/' + playlistId, 'PUT', null, options, this._auth(true));
          },

          /**
            ====================== User =====================
           */

          getUser: function (userId) {
            return this.api('/users/' + userId);
          },

          getCurrentUser: function () {
            return this.api('/me', 'GET', null, null, this._auth());
          },

          /**
            ====================== User Library =====================
           */
          getSavedUserTracks: function (options) {
            return this.api('/me/tracks', 'GET', options, null, this._auth());
          },

          userTracksContains: function (tracks) {
            tracks = angular.isString(tracks) ? tracks.split(',') : tracks;
            angular.forEach(tracks, function (value, index) {
              tracks[index] = value.indexOf('spotify:') > -1 ? value.split(':')[2] : value;
            });
            return this.api('/me/tracks/contains', 'GET', {
              ids: tracks.toString()
            }, null, this._auth());
          },

          saveUserTracks: function (tracks) {
            tracks = angular.isString(tracks) ? tracks.split(',') : tracks;
            angular.forEach(tracks, function (value, index) {
              tracks[index] = value.indexOf('spotify:') > -1 ? value.split(':')[2] : value;
            });
            return this.api('/me/tracks', 'PUT', {
              ids: tracks.toString()
            }, null, this._auth());
          },

          removeUserTracks: function (tracks) {
            tracks = angular.isString(tracks) ? tracks.split(',') : tracks;
            angular.forEach(tracks, function (value, index) {
              tracks[index] = value.indexOf('spotify:') > -1 ? value.split(':')[2] : value;
            });
            return this.api('/me/tracks', 'DELETE', {
              ids: tracks.toString()
            }, null, this._auth(true));
          },

          /**
            ====================== Browse =====================
           */
          getFeaturedPlaylists: function (options) {
            return this.api('/browse/featured-playlists', 'GET', options, null, this._auth());
          },

          getNewReleases: function (options) {
            return this.api('/browse/new-releases', 'GET', options, null, this._auth());
          },

          getCategories: function (options) {
            return this.api('/browse/categories', 'GET', options, null, this._auth());
          },

          getCategory: function (category_id, options) {
            return this.api('/browse/categories/' + category_id, 'GET', options, null, this._auth());
          },

          getCategoryPlaylists: function (category_id, options) {
            return this.api('/browse/categories/' + category_id + '/playlists', 'GET', options, null, this._auth());
          },

          /**
            ====================== Following =====================
           */
          follow: function (type, ids) {
            return this.api('/me/following', 'PUT', { type: type, ids: ids }, null, this._auth());
          },

          unfollow: function (type, ids) {
            return this.api('/me/following', 'DELETE', { type: type, ids: ids }, null, this._auth());
          },

          userFollowingContains: function (type, ids) {
            return this.api('/me/following/contains', 'GET', { type: type, ids: ids }, null, this._auth());
          },

          followPlaylist: function (userId, playlistId, isPublic) {
            return this.api('/users/' + userId + '/playlists/' + playlistId + '/followers', 'PUT', null, {
              public: isPublic || null
            }, this._auth(true));
          },

          unfollowPlaylist: function (userId, playlistId) {
            return this.api('/users/' + userId + '/playlists/' + playlistId + '/followers', 'DELETE', null, null, this._auth());
          },

          playlistFollowingContains: function(userId, playlistId, ids) {
            return this.api('/users/' + userId + '/playlists/' + playlistId + '/followers/contains', 'GET', {
              ids: ids.toString()
            }, null, this._auth());
          },

          /**
            ====================== Login =====================
           */
          setAuthToken: function (authToken) {
            this.authToken = authToken;
            return this.authToken;
          },

          login: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var that = this;

            var w = 400,
                h = 500,
                left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2),
                top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);

            var params = {
              client_id: this.clientId,
              redirect_uri: this.redirectUri,
              scope: this.scope || '',
              response_type: 'token'
            };

            var authCompleted = false;
            var authWindow = openDialog(
              'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' + this.toQueryString(params),
              'Spotify',
              'menubar=no,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=no,width=' + w + ',height=' + h + ',top=' + top + ',left=' + left,
              function () {
                if (!authCompleted) {
                  deferred.reject();
                }
              }
            );

            function storageChanged (e) {
              if (e.key === 'spotify-token') {
                if (authWindow) { authWindow.close(); }
                authCompleted = true;

                that.setAuthToken(e.newValue);
                $window.removeEventListener('storage', storageChanged, false);

                deferred.resolve(e.newValue);
              }
            }

            $window.addEventListener('storage', storageChanged, false);

            return deferred.promise;
          }
        };

        return new NgSpotify();
      }];

    });

}(window, angular));
```

**Console Log**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
  (anonymous function)  
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/ng/areq?p0=test&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:6:416
    at qb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:22:131)
    at Sa (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:22:218)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:80:81
    at O (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:59:501)
    at K (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:60:338)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:54:410)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:54:433)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js:53:480
  (anonymous function)  
  (anonymous function)  
  n.$apply  
  (anonymous function)  
  e 
  d 
  zc    
  Zd    
  (anonymous function)  
  a 
  Hf.c
```

Comment: you should create your module `app` like this, `var app = angular.module('app',[])`. Because if you are not specifying it's second parameter (here, `[]`), you are fetching an already created module not creating a new module.

Answer (score 0):

The module and the application are well defined, but these scripts tags in the body are the wrong part. Angular does not work with imperative programming.

Your body should use bindings to access the controller $scope members.

Something like this:

```
<body ng-controller='test'>
    <div ng-repeat="artist in artists">
      {{artist|json}}
    </div>
</body>
```

After the ajax request finishes, the data should be automatically displayed, or on the contrary if an error occurs, you can find more details in the developer console of the browser.

Also, the controller scope does not have a method called `getAlbum`.

So to fix these issues: (assuming that the login workflow is no longer required)

Add a controller method that loads the album data and call it from the controller itself or from another directive such as `ng-click`:

```
// inside the main controller
$scope.loadData = function () {
  Spotify.getAlbum('your album Id').then(function (data) {
    $scope.albumInfo = data;
  });
};
// call the function here or in a ng-click for instance.
$scope.loadData();
```

Present the data with bindings: (in this case formatted as a json)

```
<html ng-app="app">
<body ng-controller="test">
    <pre>{{albumInfo | json}}</pre>
</body>
```

note that the html was simplified, you must load angular, main.controller and Spotify.